# Autoit starts app without focus

Tags: autoit

Using AutoIt 3.3.14.2 to start Entrust etunprot.exe application.  The Entrust application starts, but does not have focus.  After the application starts the AutoIt script is supposed to enter the password, but doesn't because of no focus.  When I click on the application to give it focus then the password is entered and the script continues and finishes successfully.  I originally used WinWaitActive and replaced it with WinWait and WinActivate to try and fix the problem.  Here is the code:

```
; Terminate script if no command-line arguments
If $CmdLine[0] = 0 Then Exit (1)

Run("C:\Program Files\Entrust\Password Unprotect\etunprot.exe " & $CmdLine[1])

WinWait("Entrust Password Unprotect", "OK")
WinActivate("Entrust Password Unprotect", "OK")

; Enter the password text
Send("password")
; Submit the password
Send("{ENTER}")

WinWait("Entrust Password Unprotect", "Enter name of output folder")
WinActivate("Entrust Password Unprotect", "Enter name of output folder")

; Enter the name of the output folder
Send($CmdLine[2])
; Unprotect the enp file
Send("{ENTER}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WinWait("Entrust Password Unprotect", "")
WinActivate("Entrust Password Unprotect", "")
```

Comment: Tried that idea, but the behavior is the same.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the Windows of your process. Maybe it helps you out.

```
#include <Array.au3>
$re = ProcessGetWindow(ProcessExists('Greenshot.exe'))
_ArrayDisplay($re)


Func ProcessGetWindow($PId)
    $PId = ProcessExists($PId)
    If $PId = 0 Then
        SetError(1)
    Else
        Local $WinList = WinList()
        Local $WindowTitle[1][2]
        Local $x = 0
        For $i = 1 To $WinList[0][0]
            If WinGetProcess($WinList[$i][1], "") = $PId And $WinList[$i][0] <> "" Then
                ReDim $WindowTitle[$x + 1][2]
                $WindowTitle[$x][0] = $WinList[$i][0]
                $WindowTitle[$x][1] = $WinList[$i][1]
                $x += 1
            EndIf
        Next
        Return $WindowTitle
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>ProcessGetWindow
```